# Discrete-time Fourier Transform of the unit step sequence $u[n]$

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dtft, proof

From text books we know that the DTFT of $u[n]$ is given by

$$U(\omega)=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}},\qquad -\pi\le\omega <\pi\tag{1}$$

However, I haven't seen a DSP textbook that at least pretends to give a more or less sound derivation of $(1)$.

Proakis [1] derives the right half of the right-hand side of $(1)$ by setting $z=e^{j\omega}$ in the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $u[n]$, and says that it is valid except for $\omega=2\pi k$ (which is of course correct). He then states that at the pole of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform we have to add a delta impulse with an area of $\pi$, but that appears more like a recipe to me than anything else.

Oppenheim and Schafer [2] mention in this context

> Although it is not completely straightforward to show, this sequence can be represented by the following Fourier transform:

which is followed by a formula equivalent to $(1)$. Unfortunately, they didn't take the trouble to show us that "not completely straightforward" proof.

A book that I actually didn't know, but which I found when looking for a proof of $(1)$ is [Introduction to Digital Signal Processing and Filter Design](https://books.google.nl/books?id=37g8oUqaS_AC&lpg=PA303&ots=XlS_KA6FV_&dq=introduction%20to%20digital%20signal%20processing%20and%20filter%20design%20shenoi&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) by B.A. Shenoi. On [page 138](https://books.google.nl/books?id=37g8oUqaS_AC&lpg=PA303&ots=XlS_KA6FV_&dq=introduction%20to%20digital%20signal%20processing%20and%20filter%20design%20shenoi&pg=PA138#v=onepage&q&f=false) there's a "derivation" of $(1)$, but unfortunately it is wrong. I asked a ["DSP-puzzle" question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46491/4298) to have people show what is wrong with that proof.]

So **my question** is:

Can anybody provide a proof/derivation of $(1)$ that is sound or even rigorous while being accessible for mathematically inclined engineers? It doesn't matter if it's just copied from a book. I think it would be good to have it on this site anyway.

Note that even on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) almost nothing relevant is to be found: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1914904/70664) has no answers, and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772285/70664) has two answers, one of which is wrong (identical to Shenoi's argument), and the other one uses the "accumulation property", which I would be happy with, but then one needs to proof that property, which puts you back to the start (because both proofs basically prove the same thing).

As a final note, I did come up with something like a proof (well, I'm an engineer), and I will also post it as an answer some days from now, but I would be happy to collect other published or unpublished proofs that are simple and elegant, and, most importantly, that are accessible for DSP engineers.

PS: I do not doubt the validity of $(1)$, I would just like to see one or several relatively straightforward proofs.

---

[1] Proakis, J.G. and D.G. Manolakis, *Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms, and Applications*, 3rd edition, Section 4.2.8

[2] Oppenheim, A.V. and R.W. Schafer, *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, 2nd edition, p. 54.

---

---

Inspired by a comment by Marcus Müller, I'd like to show that $U(\omega)$ as given by Eq. $(1)$ satisfies the requirement

$$u[n]=u^2[n]\rightarrow U(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(U\star U)(\omega)$$

If $U(\omega)$ is the DTFT of $u[n]$, then

$$V(\omega)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}$$

must be the DTFT of

$$v[n]=\frac12\text{sign}[n]$$

(where we define $\text{sign}[0]=1$), because

$$V(\omega)=U(\omega)-\pi\delta(\omega)\Longleftrightarrow u[n]-\frac12=\frac12\text{sign}[n]$$

So we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}(V\star V)(\omega)\Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac12\text{sign}[n]\right)^2=\frac14$$

from which it follows that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}(V\star V)(\omega)=\text{DTFT}\left\{\frac14\right\}=\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega)$$

With this we get

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi}(U\star U)(\omega)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[(\pi\delta(\omega)+V(\omega))\star (\pi\delta(\omega)+V(\omega))\right]\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left[\pi^2\delta(\omega)+2\pi V(\omega)+(V\star V)(\omega)\right]\\&=\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega)+V(\omega)+\frac{\pi}{2}\delta(\omega)\\&=U(\omega)\qquad\text{q.e.d.}\end{align}$$

Comment: waaah. Don't break my world. Doubt in that formula introduces a realm of chaos. For example, $u^2(t) = u(t)$, and hence (with a cont. FT definition prefactor depending constant $c$), $$\begin{align}\text{DTFT}(u^2)(\omega) &=c\,\cdot\, U(\omega)*U(\omega) \\&=c\pi U(\omega)+ \frac{c}{1+e^{-j\omega}}*U(\omega)\\&=c\pi \left(\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\right)+\frac{c\pi}{1+e^{-j\omega}}+c\frac{1}{1+e^{-j\omega}}*\frac{1}{1+e^{-j\omega}}\\&=c\pi^2\delta(\omega)+\frac{2c\pi}{1+e^{-j\omega}} + c\frac{1}{1+e^{-j\omega}}*\frac{1}{1+e^{-j\omega}}\\&\overset{\text{magic?}}=U\end{align}$$

Comment: @MarcusMüller: No doubt about that formula, it's correct. The question is just how to show it in a way that a simple minded engineer can understand. And $u^2[n]=u[n]$ works out for the given DTFT, no problem.

Comment: I consider myself very simple-minded, and that means I worry when things don't feel "safe" when I can't see how they are derived.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Are you referring to the DTFT of $u[n]$ or the magical equality signal in your previous comment?

Comment: well, since the DTFT of u² = u should be U, and the term just above the magic (?) really doesn't look like U at all, I'm suspecting magic. So, my doubts really stem from the equality sign, but psychologically extent to the DTFT of u.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: OK. *Assuming* Eq. (1) is correct (which it is), I think I can show how $cU*U=U$. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Take a look at my edit.

Comment: what's the value of $u[0]$?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: $u[0]=1$, as is common in discrete-time (because we want it to equal $\sum_{k=-\infty}^n\delta[k]$).

Comment: @MattL. oooh nice!

Comment: well then you're gonna have to fudge things a little if you construct a unit step out of the $\operatorname{sgn}()$ function.  this is not correct: $$ u[n]-\tfrac12=\tfrac12\operatorname{sgn}(n) $$

Comment: Does $v[n]$ have a DTFT? If we divide the sum corresponding to the definition of the transform, the second half (i.e. the one that goes from $0$ to $\infty$) diverges I believe. I also think that this is the mistake in Shanoi's argument, too. Maybe I'm mistaken but I don't see where.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: It is consistent with the way I defined the discrete-time sign function $\text{sign}[n]$: $\text{sign}[0]=1$.

Comment: it's a Hilbert transform thing.

Comment: @Tendero: Everything here diverges. Welcome to distribution land!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Please check again, it's correct. With $\text{sign}[0]=1$ everything works out.

Comment: A land I'm afraid I've never explored... But what I wanted to say is, stating *that* doesn't follow the same proof Shanoi offers? Or is there another thing that is wrong with it?

Comment: @Tendero: There's something else wrong with it, nothing with diverging sums etc. Some more basic (?) thing.

Comment: I see that what you're after is not to prove whether the equation is correct or not, but rather it's to rigorously and directly **derive** $U(w)$ from first principles and definition of DTFT.  Then whenever one wants to make a rigorous proof involving **impulses** then I guess one should better refer to the cited books from generalized function theory: **Lighthill-1958** is cited in Opp&Schafer for a discussion of impulse function and its use in Fourier transforms. All other proofs will inevitably rely on the proofs made on those references and will be insufficient to replace a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Fat32: That's a valid viewpoint. I think, however, that a reasonably sound derivation is possible if we accept basic transforms such as $\text{DTFT}\{1\}=2\pi\delta(\omega)$, and if we're content to define integrals by their Cauchy principal value.

Comment: Hi: This question topic is above me, atleast at the moment, and I can't tell if Tendero or MattL asked the initial question, but, in either case, do you like the text by siego ? It's not that expensive on Amazon. Thanks.

Comment: Yes indeed. Accepting $DTFT\{1\} = 2\pi \delta(w)$ and the Cauchy principle value as the basis, then finding $U(w)$ from first principles should be possible imho. Eventhough, the fact that the authors're exclusively refraining from doing so implies that there are some not so obvious difficulties in it?

Comment: Hi Matt: Sorry, I meant B.A. Shenoi's text referred to inside the question. I can never get any comment right on this list the first time I write it. I think the time limit for comments makes me nervous and rushed !!!! LOL. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: I don't really know the text, I just know that one page with the "proof" I refer to in my question, so I can't really say much about the book.

Comment: No problem. I have so many books so I'll wait on that one until I see a + review.

Comment: MattL: Here's a simpler proof but it uses the $2\pi \delta(\omega)$ relation and probably other things that make it mathematically faulty. http://code.ucsd.edu/zeger/45/UnitStep.pdf

Comment: @markleeds: Thanks, but that proof is about the *continuous* Fourier transform of the continuous-time unit step $u(t)$, not about the DTFT of the unit step sequence $u[n]$. But maybe a similar proof is possible in discrete time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cedron Dawg posted an interesting initial point in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46498/19249). It begins with these steps:

$$ \begin{align}
U(\omega) &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}  e^{-j \omega n} \\
&= \lim_{ N \to \infty } \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}  e^{-j \omega n}\\
&= \lim_{ N \to \infty } \left[  \frac{  1 -  e^{-j \omega N}  }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega }   } \right] \\
&= \frac{ 1 }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } } - \lim_{ N \to \infty } \left[  \frac{  e^{-j \omega N}  }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } } \right]
\end{align} $$

It turns out the term inside the limit [can be expanded as follows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp(-i*w*n)%2F(1-exp(-i*w))):

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{  e^{-j \omega N}  }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } }
={}
&\frac{1}{\sin^2(\omega)+(1-\cos(\omega))^2} \cdot \\
&\left[-\cos(\omega)\cos(N\omega)+\cos(N\omega)-\sin(\omega)\sin(N\omega)+ \\
j(-\sin(\omega)\cos(N\omega)+\cos(\omega)\sin(\omega)-\sin(N\omega))\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

The common factor outside the brackets [can be expressed as](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E2(t)%2B(1-cos(t))%5E2):

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(\omega)+(1-\cos(\omega))^2} = \frac{1}{4\sin^2(\omega/2)}$$

The real part inside the brackets [also equals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-cos(t)*cos(n*t)%2Bcos(n*t)-sin(t)*sin(n*t)):

$$-\cos(\omega)\cos(N\omega)+\cos(N\omega)-\sin(\omega)\sin(N\omega)= 2\sin(\omega/2)\sin[\omega(-N+1/2)]$$

On the other hand, the imaginary part [can be rewritten as](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-sin(t)*cos(n*t)%20%2Bcos(t)*sin(n*t)-sin(n*t)):

$$-\sin(\omega)\cos(N\omega)+\cos(\omega)\sin(\omega)-\sin(N\omega)=-2\sin(\omega/2)\cos[\omega(-N+1/2)]$$

Rewritting the original term we get that:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{  e^{-j \omega N}  }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } }
&=\frac{2\sin\left(\frac \omega 2\right)}{4\sin^2\left(\frac \omega 2\right) }
\left( \sin[\omega(-N+1/2)] - j\cos[\omega(-N+1/2)]\right) \\
&=-\frac{\sin[\omega(M+1/2)]}{2\sin\left(\frac \omega 2\right)} - j\frac{\cos[\omega(M+1/2)]}{2\sin\left(\frac \omega 2\right)}
\end{align}
$$

where I used $M=N-1$ and the limit stays unaffected as $M\to \infty$ as well.

According to the [7th definition in this site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunctions/DiracDelta/09/):

$$\lim_{M\to \infty} -\frac{1}{2\sin(\omega/2)}\sin[\omega(M+1/2)] = -\pi \delta(\omega)$$

So far we have that:

$$\lim_{ M \to \infty }   \frac{  e^{-j \omega (M+1)}  }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } } =-\pi\delta(\omega)
-j\lim_{M\to \infty} \frac{\cos[\omega(M+1/2)]}{2\sin(\omega/2)}
$$

If we could prove that the second term on the right of the equality is $0$ in some sense, then we are done. I [asked it at math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2617031/308167) and, indeed, that sequence of functions tends to the zero distribution. So, we have that:

$$ \begin{align}
U(\omega) &= \frac{ 1 }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } } - \lim_{ N \to \infty } \left[  \frac{  e^{-j \omega N}  }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } } \right] \\
&=\frac{ 1 }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } }+\pi\delta(\omega)
+j\lim_{M\to \infty} \frac{\cos[\omega(M+1/2)]}{2\sin(\omega/2)} \\
& =\frac{ 1 }{ 1 -  e^{-j \omega } }+\pi\delta(\omega)
\end{align} $$

Comment: This is very nice! I checked it and everything seems to be correct, so that imaginary part must tend to zero in some sense. I'll think about it for a bit.

Comment: @MattL. Let me know if you are able to make any progress!

Comment: @MattL. The proof is finally complete!

Comment: Good work! I had figured out that the cosine term would tend to zero due to the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, but my problem was the case $\omega=0$. Because the very first formula is based on the geometric sum, which is only valid for $\omega\neq 0$. It all somehow works out after all, but that's still a minor flaw. I have another derivation that does not split out the term $1/(1-e^{-j\omega})$, in which the case $\omega=0$ is handled with a bit more care, but it's still an "engineer's proof". I might post it when I have more time.

Answer (score 4):

I'll provide two relatively simple proofs that do not require any knowledge of distribution theory. For a proof that computes the DTFT by a limit process using results from distribution theory, see [this answer by Tendero](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46511/4298).

I will only mention (and not elaborate on) the first proof here, because I've posted it as an [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46561/4298) to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46491/4298), the purpose of which was to show that a certain published proof is faulty.

The other proof goes as follows. Let's first write down the even part of the unit step sequence $u[n]$:

$$u_e[n]=\frac12\left(u[n]+u[-n]\right)=\frac12+\frac12\delta[n]\tag{1}$$

The DTFT of $(1)$ is

$$\text{DTFT}\{u_e[n]\}=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\tag{2}$$

which equals the real part of the DTFT of $u[n]$:

$$U_R(\omega)=\text{Re}\{U(\omega)\}=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\tag{3}$$

Since $u[n]$ is a real-valued sequence we're done because the real and imaginary parts of $U(\omega)$ are related via the Hilbert transform, and, consequently, $U_R(\omega)$ uniquely determines $U(\omega)$. However, in most DSP texts, these Hilbert transform relations are derived from the equation $h[n]=h[n]u[n]$ (which is valid for any causal sequence $h[n]$), from which it follows that $H(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}(H\star U)(\omega)$. So in order to show the Hilbert transform relation between the real and imaginary parts of the DTFT we need the DTFT of $u[n]$, which we actually want to derive here. So the proof becomes circular. That's why we'll choose a different way to derive the imaginary part of $U(\omega)$.

For deriving $U_I(\omega)=\text{Im}\{U(\omega)\}$ we write the odd part of $u[n]$ as follows:

$$u_o[n]=\frac12\left(u[n]-u[-n]\right)=u[n-1]-\frac12+\frac12\delta[n]\tag{4}$$

Taking the DTFT of $(4)$ gives

$$\begin{align}jU_I(\omega)&=e^{-j\omega}U(\omega)-\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\\&=e^{-j\omega}(U_R(\omega)+jU_I(\omega))-\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\\&=e^{-j\omega}\left(\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\right)+e^{-j\omega}jU_I(\omega)-\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\\&=\frac12(1+e^{-j\omega})+e^{-j\omega}jU_I(\omega)\tag{5}\end{align}$$

where I've used $(3)$. Eq. $(5)$ can be written as

$$jU_I(\omega)(1-e^{-j\omega})=\frac12(1+e^{-j\omega})\tag{6}$$

The correct conclusion from $(6)$ is (see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46561/4298) for more details)

$$jU_I(\omega)=\frac12\frac{1+e^{-j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}+c\delta(\omega)\tag{7}$$

But since we know that $U_I(\omega)$ must be an odd function of $\omega$ (because $u[n]$ is real-valued), we can immediately conclude that $c=0$. Hence, from $(3)$ and $(7)$ we finally get

$$\begin{align}U(\omega)&=U_R(\omega)+jU_I(\omega)\\&=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12+\frac12\frac{1+e^{-j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\\&=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac12\left( 1+\frac{1+e^{-j\omega}}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\right)\\&=\pi\delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{1-e^{-j\omega}}\tag{8}\end{align}$$