# Fourier transform of discrete time unit step function

Tags: fourier-transform

To obtain fourier transform of u[n],
`u[n] - u[n-1] = delta[n]` , taking fourier transform of both sides of the equation results in : 
`U(w) - exp(-jw) U(w) = 1` , hence :
`U(w) = 1/(1-exp(-jw))` which is wrong and the right answer has an extra term. 
Which step is wrong in this possible solution?
I know the right proof of fourier transform of `u[n]`, my question is regarding the wrong part of this solution.

Comment: Yes it is similar but not the same. I had seen that question but I could not find flaw of this solution. Now I got that this is wrong because we can only divide both sides by (1-exp(-jw)) when w is not zero. Hence, this solution is wrong.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46491/4298).

Comment: Yes, that is the same. Thank you.

Comment: The way I would explain the flaw in that proof is shown [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/46561/4298).

Answer (score -1):

The DFT of a unit step response is
$$U(\omega) = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j \omega}} + \pi \delta(\omega)$$
Applying the shift property as you did will give:
$$\mathcal{F}(u[n] - u[n-1]) = U(\omega) - U(\omega)e^{-j \omega} = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j \omega}} + \pi \delta(\omega) - [\frac{1}{1 - e^{-j \omega}} + \pi \delta(\omega)]e^{-j \omega}$$
that is
$$\mathcal{F}(u[n] - u[n-1]) =  \frac{1- e^{-j \omega}}{1 - e^{-j \omega}} +\pi\delta(\omega)( 1 - e^{-j\omega}) = 1+\pi\delta(\omega)( 1 - e^{-j\omega})$$
The second term is always zero because for $\omega = 0$, $1 - e^{-j\omega} = 0 $ and it's zero on any other point, so you get,
$$\mathcal{F}(u[n] - u[n-1]) = 1 = \mathcal{F}(\delta[n])$$