# Problem with the existence of inverse DTFT

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, z-transform, integration

I am having trouble on the following exercise and I can't figure out where I am doing something wrong:

> Given an LTI system described by the following difference equation: $$y(n)=x(n)+2x(n-2)+y(n-1)$$
> find the frequency response $H(e^{i\omega})$ and then find the impulse response $h(n)$ using a DTFT.

My attempt:

The difference equation becomes: $y(n)-y(n-1)=x(n)+2x(n-2)\overset{\mathcal{Z-}\text{transform}}{\Longrightarrow}Y(z)-z^{-1}Y(z)=X(z)+2z^{-2}X(z)$ and because $H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}$, $H(z)=\frac{1+2z^{-2}}{1-z^{-1}}=\frac{z^2+2}{z^2-z}=\frac{z^2+2}{z(z-1)}$ and because (here I am not so sure) the system is causal, it must be that we require $|z|>1$. Even if the ROC wasn't $|z|>1$, $|z|=1$ is a pole so it can't be in the ROC. But, the exercise is asking for a DTFT, which is the $\mathcal{Z-}$transform $z=e^{i\omega}$, so the $\mathcal{Z}-$transform on the unit circle $|z|=1$. The integral for $h(n)$ would then be
$$h(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}{\frac{z^2+2}{z(z-1)}z^{n-1}dz}$$ which obviously diverges because $|z|=1$ is a pole. Am I doing anything wrong? Because it seems to me that the problem is impossible with a DTFT. There is, however, a solution with an inverse $\mathcal{Z}-$transform. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right, the given system doesn't have a frequency response, at least not as a conventional function. There's a pole on the unit circle, so the system is not stable (actually, it is *marginally* stable).

However, the impulse response is very easy to determine. You could either iterate through the given difference equation with $x[n]=\delta[n]$ (assuming zero initial condition), or you could rewrite $H(z)$ as

$$H(z)=\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}+\frac{2z^{-2}}{1-z^{-1}}\tag{1}$$

Recognizing the first term on the left-hand side of $(1)$ as the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of the unit step sequence $u[n]$, one arrives quickly at the following expression for $h[n]$:

$$h[n]=u[n]+2u[n-2]\tag{2}$$

where I've assumed causality of the system.

Since the unit step sequence [does have a DTFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46442/4298) (if we allow generalized functions, i.e., a Dirac delta), we *can* write the frequency response of the given system as an expression with a Dirac delta impulse. But this is not something that you would try to derive from first principles, at least not as an engineer.

Comment: Thank you! I had actually gone about calculating the integral using the residue theorem and got some pretty weird $(1-n)-$ order derivatives, but these were easily discarded with the use of the $\Gamma$ function. I did get the same expression as you did, but I wondered why the problem was specifically asking for the frequency response, when there was none. I am a mathematics grad student helping an engineer friend, so I have been studying these systems for the past few days and you have been extremely helpful!