# DTFT Pair Transformation of unit step

Tags: dtft

I am not seeing a direct pair of DTFT transform of the unit step.

Comment: Looks like homework. Please plot x[n] and think about what you really need.

Comment: "I am not seeing a direct pair of DTFT transform of the unit step." Where have you been looking?

Answer (score 0):

The DTFT of the unit step sequence is the topic of [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46442/4298). However, you don't need it to solve the problem you were given. The sequence you're supposed to transform is just a finite length sequence with values $1$ in the interval $2\le n\le 7$ and zero otherwise. So computing the transform using the formula for the DTFT should be straightforward, and there's definitely no need for Dirac delta impulses.